# Trying to send mail in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I am trying to send an email with laravel 5.2. But it is throwing this error

> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0
>   Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 6sm52599778wjt.5 - gsmtp "

This is my **mail.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill",
    |            "ses", "sparkpost", "log"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.zoho.com'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => ['address' => 'fics@ficsuk.com', 'name' => 'fics'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME','fics@ficsuk.com'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Password
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
    | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
    | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
    |
    */

    'password' =>env('MAIL_PASSWORD','*****'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

];
```

this is my **mail function**

```
 Mail::send('emails.contact',$data,function($message) use($mail)
                {
                    $message->to('fics@ficsuk.com')->subject('Scholar enquiry');
                });
```

and **.env file**

```
MAIL_DRIVER= smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.zoho.com
MAIL_PORT=993
MAIL_USERNAME=you@yourdomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=lts
```

This is my first time of sending email in laravel. So please what is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to

specify `'encryption'=> env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl')`
you must use `'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465)`
and `.env` file

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_PORT=465
```

and if you want to

specify `'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587)` then
you must use `'encryption'=> env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls')`
and `.env` file

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_PORT=587
```

You are getting the error because you are specifying encryption as `ssl` while you are trying to connect through port `587` which expects to run `STARTTLS` command for `TLS` encryption.

Comment: Have you specified `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl` in your `.env` file?

Comment: Just saw that you have `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=lts` in your `.env` file if you are using port `587` change it to `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls` and if your are using port `465` change it to `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl`

Comment: In your `.env` file change `MAIL_PORT=993` to `MAIL_PORT=587` and `MAIL_ENCRYTION=tls`

Comment: i am    changed my . env file and mail.php

Comment: Can you post your current `config/mail.php` and `.env` file contents? Also are you on your local development machine or on a shared host like Godaddy?

Comment: it running on server

Answer (score 1):

Just change your mail.php in the config folder from:

```
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME','fics@ficsuk.com'),
'password' =>env('MAIL_PASSWORD','*****'),
```

to:

```
'username' => 'your@emailaddress',
'password' => 'your_password',
```